# How to show found device list on tableview using Bluetooth LE iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, bluetooth

I use follow code to connect BLE device, but in case if has many found devices, I want to show all found devices list on UITableview and then user will select the device and start connecting. My code can not show found devices list to uitableview and it can not connect when user select a device. Where is my wrong? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {


NSLog (@"Discovered peripheral: %@", [peripheral name]);
[foundArray addObject:peripheral.name]; // add peripheral name to foundarray
NSLog (@"UUID peripheral: %@", [peripheral UUID]);

NSLog (@"peripheral services before connected: %@", [peripheral services]);

NSLog(@"adversting data %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[advertisementData description]]);

[self.manager stopScan];
NSLog(@"Scanning stopped");

self.activePeripheral = peripheral;

NSLog(@"foundArray is %@", foundArray);
self.tblFound = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 320, 300) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.tblFound.dataSource = self;
self.tblFound.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.tblFound];
```

}

didRetrievePeripherals() function:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didRetrievePeripherals:(NSArray *)peripherals
{
    for (CBPeripheral *peripheral in peripherals) {
        NSLog(@"Retrieved Peripheral %@", peripheral.name);
    }

}
```

this is delegate for uitableview

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"foundArray is %@", foundArray);
    return [foundArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    }


    cell.textLabel.text = [foundArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

This is select device to connect:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
    if(self.manager.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn)
    {
        [self.manager connectPeripheral:self.activePeripheral options:nil]; // it's wrong

    }
}
```

Please give me any solutions. Thanks so much.

Comment: Is your table *completely* empty? If yes, it may be that in InterfaceBuilder you did not specify the identifier "Cell" for the prototype cell of your table. But then in your code you reference "Cell" as the ID in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @DerWOK: For now it shown found list on uitableview but I can not select device to connect. Can you show me? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For now it shown found list on uitableview but I can not select device to connect. Can you show me? thanks

You should implement one more central manager delegate's method:

```
centralManager:didConnectPeripheral:error
```

Inside it you should pass self to peripheral's delegate

```
peripheral.delegate = self;
```

At this moment you didn't discovered peripheral service nor characteristics. You should explicitly tell that you want to retrieve all services that peripheral has :

```
[peripheral discoverServices:nil];
```

After that CoreBluetooth invokes CBPeripheral delegate method :

```
peripheral:didDiscoverServices:
```

At that moment you have all services on peripheral that can be accessed via services property:

```
peripheral.services
```

Next step - discover services characteristics:

```
for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {
    [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil 
                             forService:service];
}
```

Again you need to implement CBPeripheral method from protocol:

```
peripheral:didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:error:
```

That can be accessed via

```
service.characteristics
```

Now you can read/write/setNotify on them.
But for reading/writing/notifying you should implement corresponding CBPeripheralManager protocol methods:

```
peripheralManager:didReceiveReadRequest:
peripheralManager:didReceiveWriteRequests:
peripheralManager:central:didSubscribeToCharacteristic:
```

All of that described in documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html